# 2. Topological field theories in two-dimensions$.$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory

It is known that 3d TQFTs are classified by modular tensor categories, and 2d TQFTs by Frobenius algebras.

A 3d TQFT on a manifold of the form $S^1\times M_2$ induces a 2d TQFT on $M_2$. So there must be a map from the MTC of the former to the FA of the latter. What is this map, explicitly? In particular,

1. How are the $\{\lambda_i\}$ that appear in the partition function of the 2d TQFT (cf. [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574956/84967)) fixed in terms of the modular data of the 3d TQFT?
2. Is this map bijective?

These are my thoughts regarding these subquestions:

1. I can answer this subquestion by reverse-engineering the Verlinde formula, but I am looking for a more conceptual answer rather than the solution itself. So as far as this question goes, I would appreciate if Verlinde is not used. I know what the answer is, I would like to know *where* it comes from.
2. I don't expect the map MTC$\to$FA to be injective. My intuition is that higher-dimensional theories contain more information than their dimensionally-reduced/compactified versions. A 3d object, after all, is more complex than a 2d one. From a more formal POV, MTCs carry braiding, and FAs do not, I believe. Conversely, I would expect the map MTC$\to$FA to be surjective (more generally, I feel one should be able to reach *any* $d$-dimensional QFT by reducing a certain $(d+1)$-QFT). This is probably wrong, for the following reason: any set of real numbers $\{\lambda_i\}$ determines a 2d TQFT, but 3d TQFTs only induce a discrete subset of sets $\{\lambda_i\}$ (in particular, these are always algebraic, I believe). 3d theories are very rigid (cf. Ocneanu), while 2d ones are not.

Comment: I'm not sure your expectation in 2. is entirely "obvious", since the setting of $S^1\times M_2$ is a very specific 3d setting - it would be equally reasonable to me to suspect that the 3d theory only becomes richer - i.e. non-injective - when you allow arbitrary - or at least more - 3d bases. For the converse, surjectivity would mean that the structure of the 3d theory on $S^1\times M_2$ does not impose any additional restrictions on the 2d theory on $M_2$, which I also don't think is obvious.